# Non stop "glGetError exceeded" in console

Tags: flutter, animation, package

just started a new Flutter project and installed LDPlayer emulator cause it's having a better performance, and I started to getting annoying `D/HostConnection( 4523): glGetError exceeded.` every 1 second in my Run tab, the project is using [weather_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/weather_animation) package with animation, and I'm really curious what's this log means.

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that your message is related to the `LDPlayer emulator`. Probably, it is a matter of very frequent updates of weather conditions and the emulator either just notifies about it or fails to cope with the load.